# Maximum Product of Spacings using R

Tags: r

I would like to estimate the parameter for exponential distribution using Maximum Product of Spacings (MPS). I will have to minimize:

> -(1/(n + 1))*(sum of log D[i] from i = 1 to n + 1),
>   where D[i] = F(x[i]) - F(x[i - 1])

And the following is my R code:

```
n<- 10
mydata<- rexp(n, rate=2)
x<- sort(mydata)

fnn<- function(lambda,x){
for (i in 2:n){
c<- 1-exp(-lambda*x[i])
d<- 1-exp(-lambda*x[i-1])
}
s<- (1/(n-1))*sum(log(c-d))
return(-s)
}

optim(0.8, fnn, x=x)
```

Can someone please verify if I am doing the right thing here?

The output I obtained is far from the true value of `lambda = 2`.

```
$`par`
[1] 0.92375

$value
[1] 0.1847188

$counts
function gradient 
      18       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

what modifications should I include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is rewriting `c` and `d` each time through the `for` loop. It also had a bug in the computation of the multiplicative constant `1/(n + 1)`.
Here is a corrected version. The key is to reserve memory before the loop with `numeric(n - 1)`.
I also include a simpler version, taking advantage of R's built-in `pexp`.

```
fnn <- function(lambda, x){
  n <- length(x)
  c <- numeric(n - 1)
  d <- numeric(n - 1)
  for (i in 2:n){
    c[i - 1] <- 1 - exp(-lambda*x[i])
    d[i - 1] <- 1 - exp(-lambda*x[i-1])
  }
  s <- (1/(n + 1))*sum(log(c - d))
  return(-s)
}

fnn2 <- function(lambda, x){
  n <- length(x)
  D <- log(pexp(x[-1], rate = lambda,) - pexp(x[-n], rate = lambda))
  s <- sum(D)/(n + 1)
  -s
}


set.seed(1234)
n <- 10
mydata <- rexp(n, rate = 2)
x <- sort(mydata)

opt <- optim(0.8, fnn, x = x)

opt2 <- optim(0.8, fnn2, x = x)

opt$par
#[1] 2.9225
opt2$par
#[1] 2.9225

identical(opt$par, opt2$par)
#[1] TRUE
```